# Ignite java.util.concurrent.CompletionService implementation

Tags: ignite

Not sure if there is java.util.concurrent.CompletionService implementation is provided by Ignite as in Infinispan (org.infinispan.distexec.DistributedExecutionCompletionService),

Edit:

Here is the sample code, which does not work if started in distributed mode (in Three terminals)

```
public void run(boolean isMaster, final String nodeName) throws Exception {

    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
    cfg.setGridName(nodeName); 

    Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg); 

    if (isMaster) {
        CompletionService<String> service =  new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(ignite.executorService());
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            service.submit(new Callable<String>() {

                @Override
                public String call() throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("Executing ");
                    return String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(10));
                }
            });
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Future<String> f = service.take();
            System.out.println(f.get());
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Ctrl+D/Ctrl+Z to stop.");
}
```

Terminal #1

```
mvn test-compile exec:java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dexec.mainClass="com.github.dexecutor.ignite.Node" -Dexec.classpathScope="test" -Dexec.args="s node-A"
```

Output

```
[22:29:59] Topology snapshot [ver=3, servers=3, clients=0, CPUs=4, heap=5.3GB]
Executing
Executing
Executing
```

Termincal #2

```
mvn test-compile exec:java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dexec.mainClass="com.github.dexecutor.ignite.Node" -Dexec.classpathScope="test" -Dexec.args="s node-B"
```

Output

```
[22:29:59] Topology snapshot [ver=3, servers=3, clients=0, CPUs=4, heap=5.3GB]
Executing
Executing
Executing
```

Terminall #3 : Master

```
mvn test-compile exec:java  -Dexec.classpathScope="test" -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dexec.mainClass="com.github.dexecutor.ignite.Node" -Dexec.args="m node-C"
```

Output

```
[22:29:59] Topology snapshot [ver=3, servers=3, clients=0, CPUs=4,      heap=5.3GB]
Executing 
Executing 
6
2
Executing 
4
Executing 
3
```

It should print 6 more random integers, however it blocks for ever

Here is the [whole project](https://github.com/mnadeem/test-ignite) follow the instruction in the Node class

Note : I was able to get the feature of CompletionService using 'igniteCompute.call' and 'igniteCompute.future().listen(newListener());', However I don't think that is efficient. Refer this for [example](https://github.com/dexecutor/dexecutor-ignite/blob/dexecutor-ignite-1.0.0/src/main/java/com/github/dexecutor/ignite/IgniteExecutionEngine.java)

Answer (score 0):

Ignite provides implementation of `ExecutorService`, so you can use `ExecutorCompletionService` included in JDK.

```
CompletionService<Object> service =
    new ExecutorCompletionService<>(ignite.executorService());
```

Comment: @valetin, I have update the question with more details, hope it helps

Comment: Can you share your test project?

Comment: Looks like `ExecutorCompletionService` is implemented in a very weird way  and can't be used in distributed environments. I created a ticket for implementation in Ignite: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-4093. Feel free to pick it up, it should be a good contribution to Ignite and should not be very difficult.

Comment: We have to make sure, Distributed Blocking Queue is used in the implementation... otherwise implementation would be broken again...  This is the case with Infinispan... Currently non provide one (Distributed blocking queue), Hazelcast provides one but that is not truly distributed.